# How to center dotplot with different fill than boxplot? (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

New R / ggplot user here.

I'm looking to overlay dots over a boxplot, with a different fill color than the boxplot.

Here's a reproducible example, using the built-in `mtcars` dataset:

```
mtcars$am = factor(mtcars$am, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("A", "B"))
mtcars$vs = factor(mtcars$vs, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("vs 0", "vs 1"))

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = am, y = disp, fill = am)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.3, outlier.size = 0) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = vs), size = 2, shape = 21, position = position_jitterdodge(0.15))
```

I would like the dots to be centered over the boxplots. For example, over the center of the pink boxplot, I would like blue and purple dots. Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure whether I got you right ... but to center the dots over the boxplot you could simply replace `position_jitterdodge` by `position_jitter`.

Comment: Or do without the `position = ...` part entirely, if you want the dots right in the middle of each boxplot.

Comment: Both using `position_jitter` instead of `position_jitterdodge` and leaving out the `position = ...` argument entirely worked, thanks so much!